# Conditions for diagonalization?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following matrix $A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc} a & b & 1 \\ 0 & c & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right]$. Find every values for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $A$ is diagonalizable.

I try by the following way: The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p_A(\lambda)=(\lambda-a)(\lambda-c)(\lambda-1)$. Thus it's eigenvalues are $1,a$ and $c$. If $a \neq 1, c \neq 1$ e $a \neq c$, the three eigenvalues of $A$ are different, therefore, in this case $A$ is diagonalizable. Are there other possibilities?

Comment: You need to work through the possibilities.

Comment: If you have a duplicated eigenvalue, and you can find 2 independent eignevectors the matrix is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $a=c$ and $ b=0$ . You will end up with the following matrix of Eigen vectors:

$P = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & -1\\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Since it's non-singular you can obtain the diagonal matrix by:

$ D = P^{-1}AP$ $\Rightarrow$ $D = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Thus having two Eigenvalues repeated in its diagonal entries.